# pandas - filter rows with highest sums

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

The below code demonstrates count of category entries (`b` for `business`, `e` for `entertainment`, `t` for `science/technology`, `m` for `health`) for every unique publisher. Where I need help is filtering to top ten pubishers with highest total counts of category entries.

```
pub_cat_group = headline_df.groupby(['PUBLISHER', 'CATEGORY'])['TITLE'].count()
pub_cat_group

100.7 WZLX Classic Rock                               b             1
                                                      e            11
1011now                                               b             2
                                                      e             2
                                                      m             7
                                                      t            11
106 JACK fm                                           b             8
                                                      t             1
```

I know how to pull highest individual category counts (see code below) but I don't know how to mix this logic with the above code.

```
top_pub_cats = headline_df['CATEGORY'].groupby(headline_df['PUBLISHER']).value_counts().sort_values().nlargest(10)
```

My ultimate objective is to plot category counts for the top ten publishers so that I can visualize each category's category frequency among top publications.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Harv my expected output is top ten publishers (based on the total count of titles across categories) so that I can plot each of the ten publisher's with the distribution of their unique category counts as the hue.

Answer (score 1):

Base on your description , I think you need

```
pub_cat_group = headline_df.groupby(['PUBLISHER', 'CATEGORY'])['TITLE'].count()
# I am adding the unstack, here for you to plot 
New=pub_cat_group.sort_values().groupby(level=[0,1]).head(10).unstack()
```

Update:

```
pub_cat_group.sum(level=0).sort_values().head(10)
```

Comment: this is the formatting I was hoping for, but it's printing all of the publishers and not the top ten with highest counts.

Comment: @Mr.Jibz what you mean *highest counts* for each group or for all group

Comment: If I were to sum counts for each publisher, I would then sort in descending order (highest count in index one) and then pull the top ten publishers to plot only. The logic is to show category distributions in a multi barchart without clutter. Plotting counts of each publisher would be way too messy and unreadable.

Comment: can you confirm if where that updated code fits into the original suggestion? I'm understanding the function calls, but I'm not following the full logic line by line.

Comment: @Mr.Jibz after you groupby , there is two index, you need sum with the index =0 which is PUBLISHER, then we just sort value , get the first 10